# The old church (from Littlewood's Miscellany)

Tags: puzzle

I’m in the part of the human race that doesn’t ‘get’ the following paragraph.  If you are in the *other* part, please a) wipe that smirk off your face, b) explain what I’m missing (ideally, preceded by a hint).  Thanks!

> *The old church.*  Old lady:  ‘We have a very old church here, 1913.’  ‘Oh, auntie dear, you mean 1319.’  ‘Not at all, my dear, 1325.’  (This sharply divides the human race.)

Context & credits:
The above item appears in the chapter ODDS AND ENDS of the book “Littlewood’s Miscellany,” by John Littlewood and Bela Bollobas.  That particular chapter is a collection of anecdotes, observations, puzzles, and random other stuff.

Comment: Could each person have a number? And they are referring to people and not the age of the church?

Comment: You might have better luck posting this at puzzling.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I agree it's a better fit for puzzlingSE. It doesn't fit too well here, it's not about math.

Comment: But FWIW, I don't get it either.

Comment: Erick & 6005:  Thanks much, I'll try puzzling.stackexchange.com.  MathMajor: Littlewood's puzzles tend to have the property that when the reader gets the point, it's pretty obvious; but thanks for trying.